# When does EntityManager::getReference() return null?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

The source code of Doctrine ORM claims that `EntityManager::getReference()` (and `EntityManager::getPartialReference()`) sometimes [returns null](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/01187c9260cd085529ddd1273665217cae659640/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManagerInterface.php#L153). And there is indeed such case in the [implementation](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/01187c9260cd085529ddd1273665217cae659640/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L504) as well. But I don't understand the circumstances when it actually happens and it never occurred in my projects. Can you explain how is this possible and how to reproduce such case?